# Derivative of a function defined in terms of another function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F: \mathbf{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ have continuous second order partial derivatives.  Assume its gradient is $\nabla f(0,0) = (1,2)$ and its Hessian matrix is
  $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 &4
\end{pmatrix} = \nabla ^2 f $$

Define $\phi (t) = f(t, 2t)$.  Find $\phi ^ \prime (0)$ and $\phi ^ {\prime  \prime} (0)$.

Any hints? I know how to do this when $f$ is explicitly defined, but not when just given the gradient/Hessian at a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

Just aplpy chain rule, nota that $\phi=f\circ h$, with $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $h(t)=(t,2t)$. Then

\begin{equation} \phi '(t)=\nabla f (h(t)) h'(t) \hspace{3cm}(1)
\end{equation} 
 then put $t=0$ (h' is a column vector, (1,2) as a column)

$$ \phi '(0)=\nabla f (h(0))h'(0) $$

$$ \phi '(0)=\nabla f (0,0)h'(0) $$

$$ \phi '(0)=(1,2)(1,2)^{T} $$

$$ \phi '(0)=1+4=5$$

Then derive again in (1) (which can be writenn as $[(\nabla f\circ h)(t)](1,2)^{T}$ to use the chain rule again ) to find $\phi''$ taking into account that $h'(t)=(1,2)^{T}$ (constant):

$$\phi ''(t)=[\nabla^{2} f (h(t))h'(t) ]\left[{\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]  $$

so puting $t=0$, we have:

$$\phi ''(0)=[\nabla^{2} f (h(0))h'(0)] \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right] $$

$$\phi ''(0)=[\nabla^{2} f (0,0) h'(0)] \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right] $$

$$\phi ''(0)=\{ \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   2 & 4 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \} \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]  $$

$$\phi ''(0)=\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   5 \\
   10 \\
  \end{array} } \right]  \left[{\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]  $$

$$\phi''(0)=25.$$